# How to rest BIOS password of toshiba satellite

Tags: laptop, bios, reset

I have a toshiba satellite laptop dont know the exact model its too old an the back sticker is also gone.
When i turned on my laptop after 2 years it was showing bios lock and i dont know who put that lock and whats its password.
I saw may solutions on internet but nothing works.
I saw a video where he sort two jumper and reset the password but i cant find the jumpers in my laptop 
Here are the images of my back panel of my laptop can any one help me how to reset the password.

[image]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Is the BIOS battery permanently locked in place? Might be able to see if you were to take another photo of the BIOS battery but turn the camera's flash off

Comment: @SpacePhoenix its removable

Comment: Is it able to boot into Windows or does it ask for a  password to boot into Windows? if it'll boot into Windows, which version? There might be the model number listed in Windows. Are you able to spot on the motherboard anything that could potentially be a model number?

Comment: It doesn't boot into windows ,bios ask for password and i dont know the password